# How can I force ActiveRecord to recognize a schema change in a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm working on a Rails project that has some migrations written in pure SQL for performance reasons. They are working fine until we try to run `change_column` later on. If we're trying to migrate in one pass, the `change_column` migration will fail with the following error message:

```
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL' at line 1: ALTER TABLE `articles` CHANGE `state` `web_state`  DEFAULT NULL
```

Presumably Rails has no idea we migrated via SQL in a previous migration. However, if we run `rake db:migrate` again after the failure everything works perfectly.

How can I force Rails to recognize changes make through raw SQL?

Comment: What does that SQL migration look like?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev There's nearly 30 of them. We're migrating a non-rails DB so they do everything from renaming tables to adding/removing/changing columns.

Comment: Try adding `--trace` as an arg to the rake command, to see exactly which migration is barfing.

Comment: @x1a4 it's a simple `rename_column`. The problem is that Rails doesn't know the column type of the old (`state`) column because it was added with raw SQL in a previous migration

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for reset_column_information

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/reset_column_information

But based on the error message i dont think this is the right fix

Comment: Unfortunately your gut was right. This was one of the first things I tried and no dice.